# React Router with Separate Pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a separate login and main page where after the user logs in, they are transferred to main. I am using this:

```
import Main from './Main';    // Original <App /> page
import Login from './Login';  // New <Login /> page  

// In App component  

<Router>  
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />  
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route component{NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Which works so far, however if I want to access a "page" within the `Main` component:

`<Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />`

using something like `localhost:3000/users` in the URL, it goes to a blank page. The only way to access `/users` is to start off in the `Main` component, and click on a link or button that goes to `/users`.

Does anyone know of a proper approach to this? I would like to be able to access components within the URL but also have a separate login page.

If I change `exact path='/'` to just `path='/'` it can work, but then I lose any sort of catch-all for not-found pages.

Comment: What is you using on your server side? It seems server side routing is blocking client side route.

Comment: I'm using express for api's - ie.e /api/add-user ..etc. But it is: `app.use(proxy('/api/*', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }));` for a proxy config to express @MohanBan

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `<Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />` in the App Component not in the Main Component

The `<Route>` define what component should be rendered while `<Link to>` define the url we will go after clicking. If you put the Route inside the Main Component, then it need to load Main Component first to define the route

Comment: If I include it in the App.js section, it will render as a separate page itself, and not within the /main component. For example, I have a header and footer in the main that would not show when I access /users.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the code below to achieve your desired result:

```
               <Switch>                  
                {this.props.notLoggedIn === true
                  ? <Route path='/' component={LandingPage}/>                                          
                  : <Dashboard />                    
                }
                <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
              </Switch>
```

In the above case I show the landing page as the default route and in case the user is logged in the dashboard is shown (contains more routes).  For details take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53700043/4282901)