# React Catch-All with Separate Pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I see a lot of solutions on how to create a no page found route within a SPA, but can't seem to find anything for a SPA that also uses separate pages (like a login).

For example:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/" component={Main} />
    ** a catch all route wouldn't work here **
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

The catch-all route wouldn't work above with something like `<Route component={NotFound} />` because path will get triggered at anything from `path='/'`. If I switch to `exact path='/'`, then I can't access `localhost:3000/users` from the URL, which I need when the user is logged in.

`Main`:

```
<Switch>
  <div className="someclass">  
    <Header />
    <Route exact path='users' component={Users} />
    <Footer />
  </div>
  <Route component={NotFound} /> . ** This also doesn't work here **
</Switch>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router with Separate Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698515/react-router-with-separate-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code below to achieve your desired result:

```
               <Switch>                  
                {this.props.notLoggedIn === true
                  ? <Route path='/' component={LandingPage}/>                                          
                  : <Dashboard />                    
                }
                <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
              </Switch>
```

In the above case I show the landing page as the default route and in case the user is logged in the dashboard is shown (contains more routes). To keep a handle on whether the user is authenticated or not I set the `auth` state via the submission in the landing page like

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const { value} = this.state  
    const { dispatch } = this.props

    dispatch(setAuthedUser(value))
  }
```

After this in my app I can access this and set the `notLoggedIn` prop. See

```
function mapStateToProps ({ authedUser }) {
  return {
    notLoggedIn: authedUser === null
  }
}
```

If no route is matched the `PageNotFound` component is shown.

For complete code take a look at the repo:
[Repo](https://github.com/osamamaruf/reactnd-project-would-you-rather)

Comment: thank you for the reply - this is an angle I did not think about. My approach would be something like `{notLoggedIn === true ? (
            <Route path="/" component={Login} />
          ) : (
            <Main />
          )}`. However, it would be nice to redirect to `/login` rather than display the login component within URL`/`. The other limitation would be if I enter a URL intended for Main that does not exist, it will not catch it unless I specify a route catch in Main - but that NotFound component will be shown with other components like a sidebar I generally wouldn't want.

Comment: I will upvote your answer, and also mark as solution if nothing else exists as soon as I have enough reputation. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know it helped you. For accepting an answer you don't need to have reputation. Also accepting answers earns + 2 rep (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Also `if I enter a URL intended for Main that does not exist, it will not catch it unless I specify a route catch in Main` you will not have to do this. Switch does not behave like that.. The Page not found will be shown 1) if user is not logged in 2) No route matches including the Main